# Make Transition table for DFA

Tags: computation-theory, dfa, nfa

How to convert this NFA to DFA :

[image]

From state [BC] on 'a' is not going to any state hence it is not forming a DFA

Comment: I think this is better suited for cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: This just means that the DFA doesn't accept strings where `a` comes after `b`. This can be indicated either with an incomplete NFA or DFA (as this example is) or with the introduction of a dead state that cannot be escaped and does not accept.

Answer (score 0):

In your picture, it's a little unclear which states are accepting. If all states are accepting, we can write down a trivial DFA with one state that is equivalent. So, we'll assume for the sake of argument that perhaps only some of these states are accepting.

Because A is the start state, we know that we need transitions from the state {A} for each of the symbols in our alphabet. We find {A} --a--> {A,B,C}, {A} --b--> {B,C} and {A} --c--> {C}. We have had to introduce three new states into our DFA - {A,B,C}, {B,C} and {C} - and we need transitions for these as well.

For {A,B,C} we find {A,B,C} --a--> {A,B,C}, {A,B,C} --b--> {B,C} and {A,B,C} --c--> {C}. These states are already on our to-do list, so we can continue.

For {B,C} we find {B,C} --a--> {}, {B,C} --b--> {B,C} and {B,C} --c--> {C}. We introduce a new state corresponding to the empty set, so we put that on our to-do list.

For {C} we find {C} --a--> {}, {C} --b--> {} and {C} --c--> {C}. No new states were introduced.

Finally, it is clear that {} --a--> {}, {} --b--> {} and {} --c--> {}.

We can write down the transition table as follows:

```
q            s    q'
-------------------------
{A}          a    {A,B,C}
{A}          b    {B,C}
{A}          c    {C}
{A,B,C}      a    {A,B,C}
{A,B,C}      b    {B,C}
{A,B,C}      c    {C}
{B,C}        a    {}
{B,C}        b    {B,C}
{B,C}        c    {C}
{C}          a    {}
{C}          b    {}
{C}          c    {C}
{}           a    {}
{}           b    {}
{}           c    {}
```

Depending on what states are accepting in the original NFA, this set of states is likely not minimal, but you could easily minimize this based on what states are accepting.

Answer (score 0):

```
From the above example we have to convert a DFA
STEPS TO CONVERT DFA FROM NFA:
.we have to find the individual transititions for every state.
.for every new transitition we have to find a transition.
.if any new state come we have to find a transition for the given input symbols.
.if any {} state comes it goes under the dead state.
.In DFA dead state also accepted.
.If machine reached successfully till its final string accepting state,then we say that string is accepted by our machine
```

### .But if we reach on a state where machine can't move further to its final state,then this state is called dead state

### .Dead state is known as "dummy state".

.Dead state may be required in DFA.

### .Σ={a,b,c}

### .we have 3 sates Q={A,B,C}

### .final states={A,B,C}

### .BC not goes to any state.so it moves to dead state.

```
.For every state there is a transition with every input.
.so the given figure accepted by DFA.
[NFA TO DFA][1]

[DFA image][2]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Conversion of NFA to DFA includes some steps:
Suppose there is an NFA N < Q, ∑, q0, δ, F > which recognizes a language L. Then the DFA D < Q’, ∑, q0, δ’, F’ > can be constructed for language L as:
Step 1: Initially Q’ =phai
Step 2: Add q0 to Q’.
Step 3: For each state in Q’, find the possible set of states for each input symbol using transition function of NFA. If this set of states is not in Q’, add it to Q’.
Step 4: Final state of DFA will be all states with contain F (final states of NFA)
U can see the implementation as follows

[image: Click here to see the dfa]